# How to process a POST request in a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

It seems that the default is GET; how do I process POST and other HTTP methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you send a POST request, the framework will automatically invoke the POST action. So for example if you have an HTML form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {%>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

It will automatically invoke the POST index action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ...
}
```

or you could use jquery to send an AJAX request and specify that you want to POST:

```
$.post('/home/index', function(result) {
    alert('successfully invoked the POST index action');
});
```

As far as other verbs are concerned like PUT and DELETE those are only supported in AJAX calls. You cannot specify it in an HTML form. Although there's a workaround. The following form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Destroy", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {%>
    <%= Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete) %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

will invoke this action:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Destroy() {}
```

The way this works is that the POST verb is used but an additional hidden field is sent along with the request which allows the engine to route to the proper controller action. If you use AJAX then you can specify directly the verb you want:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/home/destroy',
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I have one action to process both GET and POST? Or I need two Actions

Comment: Yes you can have a single action. This action will always be called no matter what verb has been used by the client.

Answer (score 2):

add this attribute to your action method:

```
[HttpPost]
```

Comment: This will prevent a GET request from working. He asked for both POST and GET.

Comment: @rboarman: oh, I see - you mean in his comment posted to another question AFTER my answer?  Well, I'm not clairvoyant.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure in the aspx that your processing action method is a an action for a form POST and you're good to go:

```
using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName") {}
```

ActionName is the method that will handle the POST.

Or did I misunderstand the question?